# how to implement unregisterForRemoteNotifications in ios

Tags: ios, push-notification

I want to send to the server a message when was unregister for notifications, but how can I implement it?

I wrote

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```

But where i can write my code *to send to the server*?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/unregisterForRemoteNotifications):

> **Discussion**
>   You should call this method in rare circumstances only, such as when a new version of the application drops support for remote notifications. Users can temporarily prevent applications from receiving remote notifications through the Notifications section of the Settings application. Applications unregistered through this method can always re-register.

Your server doesn't get a notification, simply when you call the function, send a data packet to your server and assume the operation was successful.

Answer (score 1):

You would do much better to use the [feedback mechanism of APNS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3) for doing device unregistration management. There are no hooks for receiving a callback when the device "actually" unregisters from push notifications. Instead, you should periodically (daily) query the feedback server and remove/deactivate devices which are reported as no longer in use.

Comment: Does this mean that after a successful   `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` the device will appear in the feedback service?